When debug metal app connected by ipad in xcode, There is some logs about Cache data printed on xcode console, why?
When run metal app connected by ipad in xcode, the console printed the log of "Cache loaded with 5598 pre-cached in CacheData and 56 items in CacheExtra.",  How can I disable these logs?

A question for you: why are you trying to disable these logs?

In general, you don't have control over "disabling" logs that are output by libraries you don't own. You can filter them out starting with Xcode 16 beta by right clicking and selecting "hide similar items" and choosing the library that produces these logs. You can do the same in Terminal, see Customizing Logging Behavior While Debugging
